# Need assistance to change number separator in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I want my number seperator should look like following.

[image]

But in my windows 10 systerm I am getting number seperatory as per following.

[image]

Kindly assist me how to change the number format as per following. 1234,56,789.00

Comment: What language packs do you have installed?  What keyboard layouts do you have installed?  Have you tried restoring the original values to verify the behavior goes back to normal?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Your digit grouping is doing exactly what you have selected

Comment: English(India) is my keyboard settings for Windows 10.Also, I am expected number separator is '1234,56,789.00'